# how to fill a recordset in vba in a module behind a db

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have tried many ways to get the job done.  I am inexperienced with the
Access VBA.
I think the problem is how to set the current database.  The code is in a module  from another db as the current db. I have paste the code here in a module behind the
currentdb that also gives the same error. I have looked after very much questions. 
It must be simple. But I don't see the answer.

```
Private Sub project()

Dim projectnamen As DAO.Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strdbName As String
Dim strMyPath As String
Dim strdb As String
Dim accapp As Object    

Path = "c:\GedeeldeMappen\programma en bestanden stiko"
strdbName="projektnamen.accdb"
strMyPath = Path
strdb = strMyPath & "\" & strdbName

'make the db "projectnamen"current. Perhaps this is possible with set??

Set accapp = CreateObject("Access.Application")  
accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase (strdb)

'fieldname is naam_van_het_project  
'tablename is projectnaam    

strSQL = "SELECT All naam_van_het_project FROM projectnaam;"

'here i get an error "can't find the object Select All naam_van_het_project
'FROM projectnaam"  error 3011

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenTable)
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    MsgBox (rs)    
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to run that query against the db which you opened in the new Access session, *accapp*.

The `CurrentDb` method is a member of `Application`.  So qualify `CurrentDb` with the object variable name of that other application session.

```vb
'Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenTable)
Set rs = accapp.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Note `OpenRecordset` won't let you use *dbOpenTable* with a query.  So I arbitrarily chose *dbOpenSnapshot* instead.  If that's not what you want, substitute a different constant from the *RecordsetTypeEnum Enumeration* (see Access help topic for details).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I followed your suggestion. I get an error "There are not enough parameters. The expected number is : 1. Error 3061

Comment: The problem is solved. First i chanced the declaration as follows;                Dim projectnamen As DAO.Database

Comment: The problem is solved. First I changed the declaration Dim projectnamen as Dao.database into Dim projektnamen as DAO.database. Second the name of the field in the db contained spaces. I deleted the spaces. Now the code works fine with your suggestions